# What is the Dojo equivalent to jQuery .live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dojo, live

What is the Dojo equivalent to jQuery .live()?
http://api.jquery.com/live/

The only solution I found was to dojo.disconnect the event handlers and re-connect them once a dynamic piece of markup was added to the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*usage* and **[demo](http://jsbin.com/ecede3/3)**

```
dojo.query("body").delegate(selector, eventName, fn);
```

*code - rewrites the original mixin-like `delegate` function of dojo*

```
dojo.provide("dojox.NodeList.delegate");
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
dojo.extend(dojo.NodeList, {
    delegate: function ( selector,eventName, fn) {
        return this.connect(eventName, function (evt) {
            var closest = dojo.query(evt.target).closest(selector, this);
            if (closest.length) {
                fn.call(closest[0], evt);
            }
        }); //dojo.NodeList
    }
});
```

*see [ticket#11459](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11459)*

You can use this more generally like jQuery `delegate`, not just as `live`, because `live` is basically a `delegate` on the document level.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification, the `delegate` function should be available in the full release of Dojo 1.6 by requiring `dojox.NodeList.delegate` (this module can be seen in the changeset at the end of the ticket linked in the answer).  1.6 RC is currently available if you're curious.  http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0rc1/

Comment: Yes it's available since 1.6: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/NodeList/delegate.html#dojox-nodelist-delegate

Answer (score 1):

I think dojo.behavior performs similar function

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
on(document, "xxx", function(){})
```

eg. in jquery: `$(".className").live(function(){})`

in dojo, it is evquilant to : `on(document, ".className", function(){})`

Actually that is what jquery.live does, it bind the event to the document to achieve the function.