# What is DOJO equivalent of jQuery delegate?

Tags: jquery, delegates, dojo, live

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Dojo equivalent to jQuery .live()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083540/what-is-the-dojo-equivalent-to-jquery-live)

Is there an equivalent of jQuery live/delegate in DOJO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is the Dojo equivalent to jQuery .live()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083540/what-is-the-dojo-equivalent-to-jquery-live)