# Idiomatic Dojo that does the same thing as YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady?

Tags: javascript, dojo, yui

I want to start manipulating a DOM element as soon as it's available, to minimize the time that it might appear in its original state on screen. I know in YUI you'd use [`YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_onContentReady) and I'm pretty sure you'd use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) in jQuery. I'm new Dojo, and I'm not sure: What's the "Dojo Way" to do this?

UPDATE: I specifically don't want to wait for the whole page (which is ridiculously data-heavy; the markup alone is potentially a MB or more) to load. I want to immediately start looking for the element in the DOM and start processing as soon as it's there, without waiting for **ALL** the markup to download, be parsed, and inserted into the DOM—that could take a relatively long time. I want to start looking at the DOM and get to work as soon as this tiny fragment is there. Given that constraint, isn't `dojo.ready` a poor fit? My understanding is that it waits for the entire DOM to be ready, similar to [`onDOMReady`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_onDOMReady).

Comment: as a Note, I believe you want to use `ready()` in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: `$(document).bind('ready', function(){ /* body here */ });` and `$(document).ready(function(){ /* body here */ });` would be equivalent.

Comment: If you have an intensely data-intensive and heavy page and what you intend to do is attach events, I think you need to be looking at a delegation-type pattern. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083540/what-is-the-dojo-equivalent-to-jquery-live this question for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most precise way of injecting functionality after a piece of DOM is added to the tree is to have the <script> that requires it placed directly below it in markup.  It seems less sexy than something like onContentReady, but onContentReady is just a polling mechanism that may end up executing your callback around the same time as domready, anyway, long after the relevant DOM subtree is ready for scripting.

Browsers can assemble a DOM tree pretty fast.  And with a polling solution such as onContentReady, you're slowing down the page assembly/render by having to execute the code that searches for the targeted element(s) every few milliseconds.

I'd stick with keeping your <script>s at the bottom of the <body> or if you must, putting the must-run-now-damnit code in a <script> after the required markup.

I am not familiar with dojo's API, so I can't answer your specific question wrt dojo if the above is not helpful.

(edited to escape the leading < in tags so they would display)

Comment: That makes sense to me, but like I said: I'm new to Dojo, and I wanted to make sure I'm doing things the way a seasoned Dojo user would expect. I'm perfectly fine just putting it inline after the relevant markup.

Answer (score 2):

[dojo.addOnLoad](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dojo/addOnLoad). There is also a newer alias dojo.ready.

**note:** Add on load also waits to be sure all required modules are loaded, in addition to waiting for DOM-readyness

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I was clear. Doesn't `ready()` wait for the DOM to be loaded? I just care about one element pretty early on in a (potentially heavy) page. I've update the question for clarity (I hope).

Comment: Yes, dojo.ready fires as soon as the DOM can be manipulated (and all required javascript modules are loaded as well) As per the docs: "Images and CSS files may or may not have finished downloading when the specified function is called"

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. `addOnLoad` requires the full HTML to have been downloaded, right? That's how I'm reading the docs. For my purposes, that is simply not acceptable. The page is not cacheable, and its size depends on user input. I've personally seen it be over 3MB just in markup, no images, css, etc. While that is a problem in and of itself, fixing it is not in scope right now. I need something that will fire as soon as an element matching a given selector (it can be `ID` in this instance) appears in the DOM, and it doesn't matter if the DOM has been fully constructed.

Answer (score 1):

`dojo.addOnLoad()` is what you want. See [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/addOnLoad.html).

Note that `dojo.ready()` is [just an alias](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/ready.html) for that method.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I was clear. Doesn't `ready()` wait for the DOM to be loaded? I just care about one element pretty early on in a (potentially heavy) page. I've update the question for clarity (I hope).

Comment: missingno has your answer there.