# alternative for jQuery .css() in Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dojo, element

I am currently working on a project in university where is allowed to use only `Dojo` (version 1.8). I have following problem: I need to set element css in javascript code. So,
any alternatives in `Dojo` for `jQuery.css()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for the `set` function in the `dojo/dom-style` module:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dom-style.html#dojo-dom-style-set

And just a thing, the correct terminology for what you are trying to do is setting the inline style of your elements. CSS is just the language used to write stylesheets.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all *future* dom elements created with the same class name?  That is, can this be done against the live dom?  How can we be notified of dom changes to nodes where className="my"?  Is it possible to essentially apply domStyle to a css element instead of a dom element?  Or must we re-query?  If we must re-query what is best event to look for to be notified of dom changes?

Comment: are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083540/what-is-the-dojo-equivalent-to-jquery-live ?